# Unable to see data entry after it's created | The JSON value could not be converted to BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier

Tags: json, rest, blazor, endpoint

Currently creating a Blazor Web app using Visual Studios.
Was able to create and delete entity data through index page:
[base page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2BQb.png)
The problems start when i try to run this data through and Edit and View pages. When I try to, I get this error chain:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: The JSON value could not be converted to BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1[[BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier, BandA.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, Applier& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier, BandA.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, Applier& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier, BandA.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[Applier](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[Applier](JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, JsonConverter converterBase)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.<ReadAsync>d__20`1[[BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier, BandA.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.<ReadFromJsonAsyncCore>d__3`1[[BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier, BandA.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<GetFromJsonAsyncCore>d__9`1[[BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier, BandA.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
   at BandA.Client.Pages.Applier.Edit.OnParametersSetAsync() in C:\Users\boris\source\repos\BandA\BandA\Client\Pages\Applier\Edit.razor:line 15
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

I looked up thie error code's meaning and it seems to be happening when the application is trying to deserialize a JSON response obtained from an HTTP GET request into an object of type BandA.Shared.Domain.Applier. The issue might be that the JSON data doesn't match the expected structure of the Applier class but I've run a GET request through Postman and can get back my data just fine:
[image: Postman Screenshot]

I'm honestly not sure how to even go about finding this problem, all related codes aren't giving back errors in Visual Studios. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Applier/Index.razor:

```
@page "/appliers/"
@inject HttpClient _client
@inject IJSRuntime js
@attribute [Authorize]

<h3 class="card-title"> Job Appliers </h3>
<br />

<a href="/appliers/create" class="btn btn-secondary">
    <span class="oi oi-plus"></span>
    Create New Applier
</a>
<br />
<br />

@if (Appliers == null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-info">Loading Appliers...</div>
}

else
{
    <table class="table table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>NRIC</th>
                <th>Date of Birth</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
                <th>Contact Number</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Address</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var applier in Appliers)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@applier.FirstName @applier.LastName</td>
                    <td>@applier.NRIC</td>
                    <td>@applier.DateOfBirth</td>
                    <td>@applier.Gender</td>
                    <td>@applier.ContactNumber</td>
                    <td>@applier.EmailAddress</td>
                    <td>@applier.Address</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/appliers/view/@applier.Id" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span class="oi oi-book"></span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="/appliers/edit/@applier.Id" class="btn btn-warning">
                            <span class="oi oi-pencil"></span>
                        </a>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(()=>Delete(applier.Id))">
                            <span class="oi oi-delete"></span>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}

@code {
    private List<Applier> Appliers;

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Appliers = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Applier>>($"{Endpoints.AppliersEndpoint}");
    }

    async Task Delete(int applierId)
    {
        var applier = Appliers.First(q => q.Id == applierId);
        var confirm = await js.InvokeAsync<bool>("confirm", $"Do you want to delete {applier.NRIC}?");
        if (confirm)
        {
            await _client.DeleteAsync($"{Endpoints.AppliersEndpoint}/{applierId}");
            await OnInitializedAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Applier/view.razor:

```
@page "/appliers/view/{id:int}"
@inject HttpClient _client
@inject NavigationManager _navManager

<h3>View</h3>

<FormComponent applier="applier" Disabled="true" />

@code { [Parameter] public int id { get; set; }
    Applier applier = new Applier();

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        applier = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<Applier>($"{Endpoints.AppliersEndpoint}/{id}");
    } }
```

Applier/Edit.razor:

```
@page "/appliers/edit/{id:int}"
@inject HttpClient _client
@inject NavigationManager _navManager

<h3>Edit Applier</h3>

<FormComponent ButtonText="Update" OnValidSubmit="EditApplier" applier="applier" />

@code { 
    [Parameter] public int id { get; set; }
    Applier applier = new Applier();

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        applier = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<Applier>($"{Endpoints.AppliersEndpoint}/{id}");
    }

    async Task EditApplier()
    {
        await _client.PutAsJsonAsync($"{Endpoints.AppliersEndpoint}/{id}", applier);
        _navManager.NavigateTo("/appliers/");
    } }
```

Applier/FormComponents.razor:

```
<EditForm Model="@applier" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />
    <fieldset disabled="@Disabled">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>First Name: </label>
            <div>
                <InputText @bind-Value="@applier.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => applier.FirstName)" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Last Name: </label>
            <div>
                <InputText @bind-Value="@applier.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => applier.LastName)" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>NRIC: </label>
            <div>
                <InputText @bind-Value="@applier.NRIC" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => applier.NRIC)" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Date of Birth: </label>
            <div>
                <InputDate @bind-Value="@applier.DateOfBirth" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => applier.DateOfBirth)" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Gender: </label>
            <div>
                <InputText @bind-Value="@applier.Gender" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => applier.Gender)" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Contact Number: </label>
            <div>
                <InputText @bind-Value="@applier.ContactNumber" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => applier.ContactNumber)" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email: </label>
            <div>
                <InputText @bind-Value="@applier.EmailAddress" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => applier.EmailAddress)" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Address: </label>
            <div>
                <InputText @bind-Value="@applier.Address" class="form-control" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(() => applier.Address)" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

        @if (!Disabled)
        {
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">
            @ButtonText
        </button>
        }
        <BackToList Target="appliers" />
</EditForm>

@code { 
    [Parameter] public Applier applier { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string ButtonText { get; set; } = "Save";
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public bool Disabled { get; set; } = false;
    }
```

Client/Shared/Domain/Applier.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BandA.Shared.Domain
{
    public class Applier : BaseDomainModel
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "First Name does not meet length requirements")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Last Name does not meet length requirements")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[STFGstfg]\d{7}[A-Za-z]", ErrorMessage = "Driving License does not meet NRIC requirements")] 
        //NRIC Regular Expression: [STFGstfg] - Upper or lower case s t f or g \ d{7} - 7 digits in between [A-Za-z] - last letter is an alphabet
        public string NRIC { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }

        //Address is not a required property, it is intentionally not given any data annotations
        public string Gender { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"(6|8|9)\d{7}", ErrorMessage = "Contact Number is not a valid phone number")] 
        //Regular mobile number Expression: (6|8|9) - start with 6 8 or 9 \ d{7} - remaining 7 digits are numbers
        public string ContactNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Email Address is not a valid email")]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        //Address is not a required property, it is intentionally not given any data annotations
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Resume> Resumes { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Application> Applications { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Client/Endpoint.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BandA.Client.Static
{
    public static class Endpoints
    {
        private static readonly string Prefix = "api";

        public static readonly string AppliersEndpoint = $"{Prefix}/appliers";
        public static readonly string ResumesEndpoint = $"{Prefix}/resumes";
        public static readonly string ApplicationsEndpoint = $"{Prefix}/applications";
    }
}
```

I tried adjusting my domain class as well as double-checking my endpoints but nothing worked. Visual Studios also says that there aren't any errors.

Comment: `Resumes` and `Applications` are defined as requiring a value in you data class, but in the Json I see them returned as `null`.  Try setting them to nullable. `public virtual List<Resume>? Resumes { get; set; }`.

Comment: It looks like you've cut some stuff out of the Postman return. It's possible the stuff you have cut out will provide a clue as to why the JSON deserialization is failing. Are you returning a collection or is the part you took a screenshot of just a property on a different object you're returning?

Comment: @Lex The stuff I had cut out is 2 others like the one I shared except they contain sensitive info so i'm refraining from sharing

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Just made migration and updated-database, same error has occured.

Comment: I've double checked with Postman on another solution I previously worked on. the 2 virtual lists are not present when calling the GET request. But I practically copy pasted before using Ctrl + H so I'm not sure what's causing this.

Comment: What happens if you do this: `applier = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<Applier>($"{Endpoints.AppliersEndpoint}/{id}", new JsonSerializerOptions{ PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true});`?

Comment: Or you can try `PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase`.

Comment: @Lex on which codes?

Comment: In your `Edit.razor` where you are calling the endpoint to get `applier`.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered the error. In my AppliersControllers, at the [HttpGet("{id}")] section, I used GetAll instead of Get. This made it so that I was loading the entire list instead of just the data at the Id.

Comment: Just FYI...this is **exactly** what I asked in my first comment based on the screenshot from your Postman call.